# Is it possible to make Wordpress PHP faster through caching or compiling it?

Tags: performance

With a Profiler I've realized that a single page wp-admin/admin-ajax.php takes 7 seconds to load because of the installed plugins.

I'd like to strongly speed it up. I was thinking of object caching or PHP compiling.

What can I do?

Comment: Caching is for _scaling_, not to hide performance problems. Plus, you don't want that for most of the AJAX calls. Find or write better plugins, or disable them for the AJAX requests.

Comment: Thanks, in the meanwhile I will disable plugins from Ajax requests. But is however not acceptable that a software takes 7 seconds on a 1 GB CPU. It means that it wastes billion of cpu cycles. There is NO solution?

Comment: I have listed **three** solutions.

Comment: I also want to stress that you really need to differentiate between WP Core and Plugins when talking about "not acceptable". When you put cracked wooden wheels on a Ferrari it also isn't the car makers fault you're slow. Also putting a stronger engine in the car won't help here...

Comment: Some plugins are just poorly written. e.g. Not using autoloader for classes and hence the memory takes a hit. If you happen to have one of these plugins you need to replace it or disable it. Many plugins use AJAX heavily , do remote API calls the wrong way, and other things. All of that hurt performance. and this is not something that caching will resolve for you. You need to allow only plugins that were well built with performance in mind. If you did all that and site is still slow, you need to scale your server resources.